# How to add Software updater in wpf without click once and any other third party tool?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application created in wpf which requires an updation when updation is available. Update is being compared from an xml file resides on server which contains software version. I have found a reference of video series of SharpUpdater on youtube link [Sharp Updater in C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=325Uxy5nVI0&list=PL3iOx6lykrwqc_KuJWIU3yAyTP2C7h_xE). It works fine for windows form application as I have downloaded and tried that in my application but when it comes to implement the same logic on wpf application it fails somewhere because the api used in this application have the references which work only of winform application. I have used another reference for auto updation [Simple Auto Update, auto patch, for WPF Apps, without the Updater Block](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/03/28/simple-auto-update-for-wpf-apps.aspx) which also doesn't seem to work for my need. I am just curious to know how to place our downloaded .exe in program files when so many restriction are there. For Updation the previous .exe I have used following snippet

```
private void UpdateApplication(string tempFilePath, string currentPath, string newPath, string launchArgs)
    {
        string argument = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{0}\" & choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}\" {5}";

        ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Info.Arguments = String.Format(argument, currentPath, tempFilePath, newPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath), Path.GetFileName(newPath), launchArgs);
        Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        Process.Start(Info);
    }
```

But it restricts me to place my downloaded file to the folder which is in program files.
Thank you for your grace.

Comment: *I don't want use click once because I have no knowledge about it*... -1. Let me get this right... you want to write a whole load of procedures instead of simply learning how to use the code that was written for that exact purpose?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/03/28/simple-auto-update-for-wpf-apps.aspx you can refer to this link this might be helpful to you.... and for background process--- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58836/Using-Background-Process-in-WPF

Comment: Exactly Sheridan. Do you have any idea about that procedures which will help me?

Comment: Yes, just read this: [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx). It'll be far quicker to learn how to use this then to write your own updater. Furthermore, once read, you'll see how easy it is to use and then in future, you'll already know how to use it.

Comment: I have many ideas on how to do that, but as you can see from all of the Close Votes that you have received so far, your question is off-topic and I'm not about to waste hours explaining all of it to you when there is a perfectly viable pre-existing technology (ClickOnce) that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you not to reinvent the wheel, and go with an existing, proven solution. While an auto-updating client seems simple at first, it can easily get difficult and into a mess if you're not covering various scenarios from the start.

### ClickOnce

ClickOnce has good built-in support in Visual Studio, .NET and Windows, but you can also run into security and deployment issues with it, especially if you're using a self-signed certificate. While I haven't had any huge issues with it, a lot of people feel badly about ClickOnce (but I'm not aware of a list anyway, as what I've read isn't normally backed up with specific technical details).

I'd be of the opinion that ClickOnce would be acceptable for internal or small projects, but not manageable for a wider release, especially across more than one customer.

### Squirrel

[Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) is a free, open source install and update solution.

If you've tried Visual Studio Code, then you've already experienced what a Squirrel install and update is like.

It is a one-click install that deploys to the user's local app data folder, so no administrative permissions / UAC is required. You can let it work using its defaults, or use their API to have more control over the update process. And if you don't like certain parts of it, you can always fork it and alter it for your own needs.

Comment: David I want my application to be deployed via unattended installation so I want this updater to be in code logic as it happens in most of software and I haven't found if any of software is deployed with click once. Is it not possible to download updated exe and replace it with the existing exe. I want this type of fundamental to be implemented. As I mentioned about SharpUpdater in my question that is perfect in case of windows application and I want that to be done with wpf also. So if you have any manual updation for my application so please provide me. Thanks.

Comment: Squirrel lets you silently install (setup.exe -s), and also lets you update the application in the background when it starts. If you really wanted to force the app to be updated, you could check and install updates when the app starts, then automatically restart it.

Answer (score 0):

wyBuild AutomaticUpdater control

The AutomaticUpdater control is included with wyBuild and it can be included with your applications royalty free. It works with Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012 and .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5. It works with all .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, etc.)

[automatic-updates](http://wyday.com/wybuild/help/automatic-updates/)